# Overriding Rails SASS Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am using rails 4.1.8, sass-rails 4.0.3 and bootstrap-sass 3.3.3 and I am having a hard time overriding some css.

My application.css.sass file looks like this

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */


@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

I have another file called header.css.scss and I am trying to give the header tag a font-size and it wont change.  However the other 3 properties change correctly when i test.

```
header{
  background: #0099da;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2em;
  height:100px;
}
```

The same thing happens when I try to change the legend tag.

Comment: Not enough code here to reproduce.  Likely a CSS specificity issue (aka. not a Sass problem).

Comment: @cimmanon the bootstrap code seems to be compiled last so it overrides much of  my header.css.scss

Comment: You're going to need to check your browser's inspector to see what's going on.  If you're overriding TBS styling, it needs to go *after*, not before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `header.css.scss` *after* `bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretending `header.css.scss` is in the same folder as `application.css.scss`, it should looks like:

```
/*
 * (…)
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

I simply changed Sprockets requirement order.

But I highly encourage you to import files specifically to avoid precedence nightmare caused by wrong import order.

```
/*
 * (…)
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require header.css.scss
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```